# Why show reputation on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why does meta show all this reputation data, if there is no rep for meta?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that since all the SE sites and their metas use the same software (I think...), it's just there by default, but it's set to display our rep from the parent site. Although, I only checked here and on Programmers; SO is different - it seems to have seperate reputations for SO and SO's meta ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=accounts) - notice his meta rep and SO rep). Not sure why it's different here, though.

Comment: Meta-SO is basically its own Stack Exchange site, and seems to double as a meta for the entirety of Stack Exchange (perhaps earning it its independence).

Comment: This is not showing rep from the parent site; it is for questions and answers on meta; it just doesn't get applied anywhere.

Comment: @jay - That's what I meant. The reputation activity is there by default because that's how all the SE sites are, but it's not applied anywhere since it's a meta site, and instead we see our rep from the parent site.